# Echo showing wrong variable value in bash after a while block. Why?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I wanted to make a quick script to count the number of lines my .scala files have:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0;
find -iname "*.scala" | while read f; do
    lc=$(cat $f | wc -l);
    counter=$((counter+lc));
    echo "$lc $counter";
done
echo "final result: $counter";
```

But unfortunately this prints

```
20 20
204 224
212 436
final result: 0
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused because you use a [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) before your while loop.

By doing so, `bash` automatically creates a new subshell. All the modifications you do will be executed in the new context, and will not be propagated when the context closes.

Use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) instead :

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0;
while read f; do
    lc=$(cat $f | wc -l);
    counter=$((counter+lc));
    echo "$lc $counter";
done < <(find -iname "*.scala")
echo "final result: $counter";
```